# Call from URL showing blank records

Tags: php, mysql

I have an option menu (selFilter) that filters a MYSQL query. The option menu choice is used in a link to filter a second PHP page.
export.php?recordID=

```
<select name="selFilter" id="selFilter" onchange="formFilter.submit()">
    <option value="%">all levels</option>
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetLevel['Level']?>"<?php if   
($varFilter_Recordset3 == $row_RecordsetLevel['Level']) {echo 'selected';}   
?>>level: <?php echo $row_RecordsetLevel['Level']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_RecordsetLevel = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetLevel));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetLevel);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($RecordsetLevel, 0);
  $row_RecordsetLevel = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetLevel);
 }
 ?>
  </select>
```

The second php page uses a query to export to .csv using the following:

```
$colname = "%";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
$colname = $_GET['recordID'];
}


$query = sprintf( 'SELECT Name, ID
FROM schedule WHERE Level LIKE %s ORDER BY Name', 
GetSQLValueString("%".$colname."%", "text"));

$result = mysql_query( $query, $conn ) or die( mysql_error( $conn ) );
//
// send response headers to the browser
// following headers instruct the browser to treat the data as a csv file 
called export.csv

//
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv' );
```

Everything works fine when an option (selFilter) is chosen in the index.php file and I click export.php. The problem is if I don't pick anything in the option menu and click export.php link, the URL string is then export.php?recordID= with recordID being blank. That blank causes nothing to export, zero records. If I select an option menu level and then click all levels the URL is export.php?recordID=% and exports correctly. What should I fix so I can export from either call?

I have tried the following but export URL is still blank:

```
export.php?recordID=<?php $filter=$_POST['selFilter']; if (!empty($filter)) { echo "%"; } ?>
```

Comment: `while (...);` <<< end of statement and is considered as "valid" syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your recommendation. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: it means that the semi-colon is "ending" your statement; remove it.

Comment: When I remove the ; in } while ($row_RecordsetLevel = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetLevel)); to } while ($row_RecordsetLevel = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetLevel)) I get an error and page does not load.

Comment: I still need help. Is there something I should change in $colname = "%"; or in WHERE Level LIKE %s ORDER BY Name', 
GetSQLValueString("%".$colname."%", "text"));

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Page wont load. I am using Dreamweaver to edit. Also shows syntax error in Dreamweaver if I remove the semicolon.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then. Something else is breaking your code and you're already checking for errors in your query. Yet, you never said what the error was.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rows' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';'...

Comment: Should the export link be changed to something else? export.php?recordID=<?php echo $_POST['selFilter'];?>

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The semicolon would be an issue if it was a `while` loop, but it is actually a `do ... while` loop - and therefor the semicolon is _necessary_ here to end the statement, removing it will cause an error.

Comment: Just check if `$_GET['recordID']` is an empty string, and if so, modify it accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe ah ok, thanks for clearing that up for me then. I'll be going to bed tonight feeling a little less stupid *lol* (Expressions in my language don't translate so well, but you get my gist (I hope)).

Comment: Can someone offer an example based on CBroe's response? "Just check if $_GET['recordID'] is an empty string, and if so, modify it accordingly."

Comment: I never received any help with this.

Comment: I have tried the following but export URL is still blank: export.php?recordID=<?php 
 $filter=$_POST['selFilter'];
 if (!empty($filter)) {
 echo "%";
}
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Changed export link to:

```
 export.php?recordID=<?php 
$filter=isset($_POST['selFilter']) ? $_POST['selFilter'] : '%';
 echo "/export_student.php?recordID=$filter";
 ?>
```

Used solution from stackoverflow: [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I just substituted

```
$filter=isset($_POST['selFilter']) ? $_POST['selFilter'] : '';
```

with

```
 $filter=isset($_POST['selFilter']) ? $_POST['selFilter'] : '%';
```

since my query was triggering an undefined index based on my option menu did not set a value.